# Categorias página web HTML

Tags: html5, css

Buenas a todos, llevo apenas 1 semana en el tema de la programación web y estoy haciendo una página usando HTML y CSS. Tengo ya mi página principal diseñada, pero no se que tendría que hacer si quiero escribir artículos en ella y ordenarlos por categorías. Más especificamente, la web va dirigida a un escritor y me gustaría tener diferentes secciones donde postear lo que vaya escribiendo. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Buenas @AGeekM, para lo que quieres hacer deberías a empezar a aprender lenguajes de programación que se ejecutan en el servidor y no en el cliente (PHP), ya que deberías almacenar los artículos con sus respectivas categorías, te recomiendo que empieces por cosas sencillas, llevando tan solo 1 semana programando aplicaciones Web no es recomendable que empieces haciendo lo que formulas, si no comenzar con cosas más sencillas

Comment: ¿Quieres crear un CMS? Si estás empezando a programar no lo lograrás, por el contrario, te frustarás porque hay muchos conceptos medios/avanzados que debes manejar muy bien. Si te urge, puedes usar Wordpress, Blogger (que te permite editar la plantilla al 100%), Ghost, etc.

Comment: @GustavoGarcía gracias por la respuesta, no me urge ninguna prisa. Quiero empezar en este mundo e ir aprendiendo poco a poco. Entonces para empezar, si quiero crear una sección únicamente, ¿ Qué debería hacer exactamente?. ¿Por donde me aconsejarías empezar?. Destacar que no quiero usar Wordpress para nada y que ya llevo unos 2 años programando pero nunca orientado a la web. Gracias de antemano.